# How to find out if a data is not null using if statement in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I am studying smarty right now. And I found out that it is really good. But I encountered an error and I don't have an idea how to fix this. Because I have a code written in PHP and I convert this into smarty template.

I have an if statement but when validating the data I got an error

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in addons/maptool/views/maps/update.tpl line 59]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: if(!$locations.updated_lat ? $locations.updated_lat : $locations.geo_alt) (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 445)
```

My goal is to simply validate if the variable is not empty or not equal to 0. What I did is:

```
<div class="map_canvas" align="center" id="map_canvas_{$locations.company_id}" style="width: 800px; height: 300px; margin: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #0a9ccc" data-company-city="" data-company_id="{$locations.company_id}" data-label="{$locations.company}" data-lat="{if(!$locations.updated_lat ? $locations.updated_lat : $locations.geo_alt)}" data-long="    {if(!$locations.updated_long ? $locations.updated_long : $locations.geo_long)}"></div>
```

Here's the part of smarty if statement:

```
{if(!$locations.updated_lat ? $locations.updated_lat : $locations.geo_alt)}
```

I don't have a problem in data but the if statement is the error. Ok that's all thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `|default` modifier to test of a variable is defined or not, you may need to write your own to test if for being empty.

`{if $locations.updated_lat|default:$locations.geo_alt}`

Comment: Ok I have an error

Fatal error: Smarty error: [in addons/maptool/views/maps/update.tpl line 80]: syntax error: mismatched tag {/foreach}. expected {/if} (opened line 55). (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 2299) in C:\wamp\www\www.hallohallotown.com\lib\templater\Smarty.class.php on line 1095

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using the following code

```
{if "" != $var)
```

This check of the variable is not Null or empty